# How do you create a method for a custom object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

Is it like...

```
var obj = new Object();

obj.function1 = function(){
    //code
}
```

or something like that?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
var newObj = {
    met1 : function () {
        alert('hello');
    }
};
```

Then, the method can be called like such :

```
newObj.met1();
```

Btw, when declaring a new object, use the object literal (`{}`), not the `new Object()` constructor.

Comment: "when declaring a new object, use the object literal (`{}`), not the `new Object()` constructor." - Why's that?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: I believe there is no logical difference, but object literals are more compact, allow setting properties in the same statement, and are generally the more accepted way to do it (http://stackoverflow.com/q/4597926/1175459).

Answer (score 92):

You can see from the answers that you have already that there is more than one way.

```
#1
var o = new Object();
o.method = function(){}

#2
var o = new Object();
o.prototype.method = function(){}

#3
function myObject() {
    this.method = function(){}
}
var o = new myObject();

#4
function myObject() {}
myObject.prototype.method = function(){}
var o = new myObject();

#5
var o = {
    method: function(){}
}
```

#3 and #4 are using a constructor function. this means you can use them to create a number of objects of the same 'class' (classes don't really exist in JavaScript)

#4 is different to #3 because all objects constructed with #4 will share an identical 'method' method because it is a property of their prototype. This saves memory (but only a very tiny amount) and if you change the method of the prototype, all #4 objects will immediately be updated - even if they've already been instantiated.

#1, #2 and #5 are all pretty much equivalent. This is because there will probably only ever be one of them at a time, so the fact that #2 has the method added to the prototype doesn't really matter. (not taking cloning into account)

There are still more ways of adding methods to objects using factories with closure or adding 'static' properties/methods to functions or private nested functions... :)

Comment: How can I define method (for example `hasClass`) for every HTML element?

Comment: #2 doesn't work. Please remove it from an answer with 72 upvotes :-)

Answer (score 13):

Generally use the [prototype](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_math.asp) property:

```
function YourObject()
{
    //
}

YourObject.prototype.yourMethod= function()
{
   //
}
```

One thing I haven't seen anyone mention yet is why you might want to use the `prototype` property over, say, object-literal notation:  doing so ensures the function definition gets shared across all instances of the objects created from your function prototype, rather than once per instantiation.

Comment: Uh, no, actually that does not work. You can add methods to an object by adding them to the prototype property of a function and then instantiating it, but not by modifying a property named "prototype" on an instance.

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant, yes; I've been coding ActionScript all morning. :)  I'll correct.  Hey and thanks to whoever downvoted me; appreciate that.

Comment: Corrected, and removed my down-vote. FWIW, i down-voted you because your example was incorrect and you were at the top of the list - sadly, not everyone bothers to verify that the answer they're upvoting is actually valid.

Comment: Thanks. And FWIW, I do check my follow-up comments diligently; as soon as I saw yours, I began the correction.  Downvoting wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry bro, here the code is:

```
  var myObj=function(){
      var value=null

     this.setValue=function(strValue){

     this.value=strValue;
     };

     this.getValue=function(){
     return this.value;
     };    
};
```

You can call this object like this:

```
    var obj= new myObj();
    obj.setValue("Hi!");
    alert(obj.getValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Function.prototype.implement = function(member, value) {
   this[member] = value;
   return this;
}

function MyFunction() {
 //...
}

(function($){

 $.implement("a", "blabla")
 .implement("b", function(){ /* some function */ })
 .implement("c" {a:'', b:''});

})(MyFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

With [es6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) you can do it like this:

```js
var a = {
    func(){
        return 'The value';
    }
}
    
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = a.func();
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: You should mention that this is not ES5, and will not work everywhere.

Comment: See [How does this module method run without the “function” keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32404617/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following instead of using the "Object.create()" method.

Function call:

```
com.blah.MyChildObj.prototype = createObject(com.blah.MyParentObj.prototype, 
    com.blah.MyChildObj);
```

Function definition:

```
function createObject(theProto, theConst) {
    function x() {};
    x.prototype = theProto;
    x.prototype.constructor = theConst;
    return new x();
}
```