# How do I create methods for an HTML element?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple, small and basic javascript framework just for learning purposes.
But the thing is that i'm allready stuck at the very basics.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$('testdiv').testFunction();
```

And the code i've written for that:

```
var elementID;
var smallFramework = {

  $:function(id) {
    this.elementID = id;
  },

  testFunction:function() {
    alert(this.elementID);
  }

};
window.$ = smallFramework.$;
```

But in return I get:

```
$('testdiv) is undefined
```

Can anyone help me with this small and hopefully easy question?

Comment: You really should try to have a better title when on your next question. The current title is not very descriptive.

Comment: @starko, I tried to fix his up somewhat.

Comment: @simucal, I'm not totally sure that's what he's asking about. I think you just made the title worse.

Answer (score 2):

To get the behavior you're expecting, you need the `$` function to return an object with a method named `testFunction`.
Try:

```
var smallFramework = // an object for namespacing
{
  $:function(id) // the core function - returns an object wrapping the id
  {
    return {                    // return an object literal
      elementID: id,            // holding the id passed in
      testFunction: function()  // and a simple method
      {
         alert(this.elementID);
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Of course, there are [many other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504803/how-do-you-create-a-method-for-a-custom-object-in-javascript) to achieve the behavior you desire.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to add methods to an HTML element you could do something along these lines.

```
$ = function( elementId ) {
    var element = document.getElementById( elementId );
    element.testFunction = function(){
        alert( this.id );
        return this; // for chaining
    }
    return element;
}

$('test').testFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
smallFramework.$('testdiv');
```

instead. According to the code you posted, that's where your `$` function ended up.

Or alternatively, it looks like you're trying to replicate something like jQuery. You might want to try something like this.

```
var $ = smallFramework = (function () {
   var f = 
   {

     find:function(id) {
       f.elementID = id;
       return f;  //every function should return f, for chaining to work
     },

     testFunction:function() {
       alert(f.elementID);
       return f;
     }

   }

return f.find  //the find function will be assigned to $. 
//and also assigned to smallFramework.
//the find function returns f, so you get access to testFunction via chaining
// like $("blah").testFunction()

})() //note this function gets called immediately.
```

this code may look confusing to someone new to JavaScript because it depends heavily on the concept of closures. I suggest that if this doesn't make sense, spend some time at Douglas Crockford's JavaScript website. This is important because the code above will bite if you happen to use `this` in the find function because `this` won't be bound to `f`, as you may expect it to be when you use it from `$` or smallFramework.