# Object properties being set by another function (not expected) javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Having an issue where an object method is not running as expected. 
When I run `ndData.recipe()`, it updates the `ndData.recipeData` object as expected, adding new values to the previous ones.

But when I call `ndData.update()`, and then run `ndData.recipe()` again, instead of the new values being added to old ones, the old values are being replaced by the new values.

I think my error might be involved in improper scoping of variables, but I'm not sure.

```
var ndData = {

initData: null,
newData: null,
recipeData: null,
ingredients : 0,

load : function(NDB_No){

    var options = [];
    $.getJSON(('scripts/jsonencode.php?q=' + NDB_No), function(data) {
        $.each(data.measurements, function(key, val) {
            options.push('<option id="wgt' + val.Seq + '" value="' + val.Gm_Wgt + '">'+ val.Amount + ' ' + val.Msre_Desc + '</option>');
            options.join('');
            $('#servSelect').html(options);
         }); 

        ndData.initData = data;
        ndData.newData = data;
        ndData.recipeData = data;

        ndData.print(ndData.initData, '#ndDataTbl');

      });

},

print : function(pdata, div){
    var items=[];
    var options=[];
    var wtRatio = 1;

    $.each(pdata.properties, function(key, val) {

        if ($.isNumeric(val)){
            val = Math.round((val * wtRatio)*10)/10;
            }

        items.push('<tr>');
        items.push('<td id="">'+ key +" : " + val + '</td>');
        items.push('</tr>');
    });

  $(div).html((items.join('')));
},


//Seems that when this update() function is called, ndData.recipeData is set to ndData.newData


update : function(){ 

    var GmWt = ($('#servSelect').val())*($('#servQty').val());
    var wtRatio = GmWt/ndData.initData.properties.GmWt_1;

    $.each(ndData.newData.properties, function(key, val) {

        if ($.isNumeric(val)){
            parseFloat(val);
            parseFloat(wtRatio);

            val = Math.round((val * wtRatio)*10)/10;
            }

        ndData.newData.properties[key] = val;

    });
    console.log('update val: ' + ndData.newData.properties.Refuse_Pct);
    ndData.print(ndData.newData, '#ndDataTbl');
},

recipe : function(){

    if (ndData.ingredients > 0){
        console.log("inregedients > 0"); 

         $.each(ndData.newData.properties, function(key, val){

            if($.isNumeric(val)){
                val = parseFloat(val);
                ndData.recipeData.properties[key] = parseFloat(ndData.recipeData.properties[key]);
                ndData.recipeData.properties[key] += val;

                console.log('val: ' + ndData.recipeData.properties[key]); // after ndData.update() is called,
                                                                          // this is logging the value of ndData.newData.properties[key]
            }
        });

    }else{
       console.log("inregedients == 0");
       ndData.recipeData = ndData.newData; 
    }


// after calling ndData.update(), this is printing properties of ndData.newData,
// when I expect properties of ndData.recipeData

 ndData.print(ndData.recipeData, '#recipeDataTbl');

 ndData.ingredients++ ;

}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set your class as an object literal. That's not a bad thing to do, but the way object literals work is that there can only be one instance of it, and any data that goes in there, will be replaced.

You may want to look at [other ways to create classes](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) and perhaps look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859800/should-i-be-using-object-literals-or-constructor-functions) on stackoverflow to understand a little bit more about object literals.