# Knockout: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, mvvm, knockout.js

Im getting an **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined** when calling *widget.Test()* in the beforeAppear.

```
define(
          //-------------------------------------------------------------------
          // DEPENDENCIES
          //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        ['knockout'],

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
        // MODULE DEFINITION
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
        function (ko) {

        "use strict";

        return {

            First_Arr: ko.observableArray(['arrayItem0', 'arrayItem1', 'arrayItem2', 'arrayItem3']),
            Second_Arr: ko.observableArray(['arrayItem0', 'arrayItem1', 'arrayItem2']),

            Test: function(widget, event) {            

                var element = event.target;          
                var pathname = location.pathname;
                var anotherArray = [
                    ["/some-url-path", widget.First_Arr()],
                    ["/some-other-url-path", widget.Second_Arr()]
                ];

                for (var i = 0; i < anotherArray.length; i++) {
                    // Do some stuff and console.log the array items                        
                }

            },

            beforeAppear: function(page) {

                var widget = this;
                widget.Test();

            }
        }
    }
);
```

The strange thing is, if I create a button in my view for example:

```
<button id="btn-click" data-bind="click: Test">test</button>
```

And click it, then I get the desired results of printing out the contents of my array to the console as expected.

PS. I tried commenting out the *var element = event.target;* line since I figured this was the source of the problem however this just produced the following: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'First_Arr()' of undefined.**

A bit at a loss with this one. Any assistance would be helpful.

Comment: Is this issue resolved or are you still having trouble getting it to work?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `widget.Test()` you aren't passing it an event parameter so `event` will be undefined and `event.target` will error because `target` doesn't exist on "undefined". In a click binding the click "event" is automatically passed into the function.

The second issue is that `var widget = this;` is essentially setting `widget = beforeAppear;`. Within a function "this" refers to the function itself. See [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Instead of defining your module as an object literal you might have better luck using a constructor function instead. See [Should I be using object literals or constructor functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859800/should-i-be-using-object-literals-or-constructor-functions)

That would probably look something like:

```
define(
          //-------------------------------------------------------------------
          // DEPENDENCIES
          //-------------------------------------------------------------------
        ['knockout'],

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
        // MODULE DEFINITION
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------
        function (ko) {

        "use strict";

        return function(){
            var self = this;

            self.First_Arr = ko.observableArray(['arrayItem0', 'arrayItem1', 'arrayItem2', 'arrayItem3']);
            self.Second_Arr = ko.observableArray(['arrayItem0', 'arrayItem1', 'arrayItem2']);

            self.Test = function(widget, event) { 
                var element = event.target;          
                var pathname = location.pathname;
                var anotherArray = [
                    ["/some-url-path", self.First_Arr()],
                    ["/some-other-url-path", self.Second_Arr()]
                ];

                for (var i = 0; i < anotherArray.length; i++) {
                    // Do some stuff and console.log the array items                        
                }    
            }

            self.beforeAppear = function(page) {
                //var widget = this;
                self.Test();    
            }
        }();
    }
);
```