# Difference between "{}" and "new Object()"

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [creating objects - new object or object literal notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597926/creating-objects-new-object-or-object-literal-notation)

What exactly is the difference between the following:

```
var myData = new Object();
myData["name"] = "ATOzTOA";
myData["site"] = "atoztoa";
```

and

```
var myData = {};
myData["name"] = "ATOzTOA";
myData["site"] = "atoztoa";
```

**Update**

What I got is this...

```
var myData = {
    "name" : "ATOzTOA",
    "site" : "atoztoa",
};
```

is a shortcut to

```
var myData = new Object({
    "name" : "ATOzTOA",
    "site" : "atoztoa",
});
```

Am I right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597926/creating-objects-new-object-or-object-literal-notation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference (technically). `{}` is just a *shortcut* for `new Object()`.

However, if you assign an *object literal*, you may directly form a new object with multiple properties.

```
var myData = {
    name:   'ATOzTOA',
    size:   'atoztoa'
};
```

..which might feel more convenient. Also, it reduces the access on the object and is ultimately faster. But that is about microoptimizations. More important is that its a lot less to type.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing. `{}` just a **short hand** for `new Object()`

Its same logic as your full name is **'Mark Zuckerberg'** and people call you **' Hi Mark'**

Answer (score 0):

No difference in my view , Both are initializing the object. nothing else , it is a shortcut.