# Why does jslint prefer {}.constructor(obj) over Object(obj)

Tags: javascript, jslint

Both will detect objects and not primitives.

It seems like a purely syntactical difference.

```
// jslint prefers {}.constructor(obj) over Object(obj)
// called isObject by underscore
// will test only for objects that have writable keys
// for example string literals will not be detected
// but arrays will
var isWritable = function (obj) {
    return {}.constructor(obj) === obj;
};
```

Comment: I think it may have something to do with how fast the javascript runs. `{}.constructor(obj)` probably has some sort of optimization in most javascript engines that `Object(obj)` doesn't have.

Comment: @user, do you mean `({}).constructor(obj)`? Plain `{}.constructor(obj)` results in a syntax error on my browser.

Comment: The code I posted above works fine.  But when I break it up and put it in the console I get the same error you did.  Weird.

Comment: @user, never mind, that's the `return` keyword. It prevents the parser from interpreting `{}` as an empty statement block. That code indeed runs fine.

Comment: The only thing I could possibly think of is that `Object` is not a reserved word, so a jerk could say: `Object = function(x) { /* be a jerk */ }` where as `{}.constructor` will always get you the object constructor.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure, as it shouldn't. If you're looking at performance, then that's the opposite of what you should be doing.

According to [this JSPerf test available which compares the speed of creating via `new Object()`, `Object.create().new()`, and `Object.prototype.constructor()`](http://jsperf.com/obj-create-vs-new/2) (which is the same as `Object.constructor()`); `Object.constructor()` is the **slowest one of them all** by far.

Google's V8 engine is magnitudes faster using the `new Object()` because it optimizes the call so heavily, so I really wouldn't worry about it.

### Results from the JSPerf test:

[image: Operation per second comparison of Object creation functions]
[image: The graph results of the speed of the different Object creation functions in multiple browsers]

Answer (score 1):

This is a false positive. Use `Object`, it is more concise, clearer and faster.

It is understandable that "[*JSLint does not expect to see `new Object`.*](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#new)" - you [should use an object literal instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4597926/1048572). However, the same warning is mistakenly issued [even if `Object` is called as a function](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/a2935fbda12c4c2de57de1761d4a50c166a5b3ce/jslint.js#L2887). This might be to detect `Object()` creations, but there is nothing wrong with calling `Object` with an argument.

Comment: You should file a bug to jslint, this looks like one.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I've sent an email, looks like there is no bug tracker.

Comment: …but all I got back was the comment "*No. Don't do that.*". So to make JSLint happy, we seem to should a) alias `Object` with some other name (`var o = Object; return o(obj) === obj;`), or b) use the only little longer `(obj !== null && typeof obj === "object") || typeof obj === "function";`