# onclick event not firing based on boolean flag

Tags: javascript, onclick, popup

I'm working on some code where if a user clicks on a particular button, that person is NOT presented with an exit popup upon exiting the page. The way I'm doing it is by setting a flag whenever the user clicks on the button. However, my code isn't working as expected: The popup loads whether or not the button is clicked. I don't understand why.

Edit: Help!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test!</title>

        <script>
            var bool = false;
            var config = new Object();
            config.surveyID = 3155031;
            config.takeSurveyURL = 'http://www.supporterfeedback.org/a/TakeSurvey';
            config.windowPositionLeft = 200;
            config.windowPositionTop = 300;
            config.home = 'http://www.surveyanalytics.com/';
            config.isRightToLeft = false;
            config.showFooter = true;

            // document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function()
            //      {
            //          bool = true;
            //      }; 
            function flag() {
                bool = true;
            }

            if (!bool) {
                window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                    QP_popupMain();
                };
            }
        </script>

        <script language="javascript"
            src="http://www.surveyanalytics.com//javascript/exitSurveyInvitation.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
        <noscript>

            <a href="http://www.supporterfeedback.org/a/TakeSurvey?id=3155031">Start Survey</a>

        </noscript>
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="http://google.com"><img id="btn" onclick="flag()"
            src="http://kelowna.directrouter.com/~jeasprco/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/PanicButton2.png"/></a>

        <p>Hello, this is a test!</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `new Object()`, use `{}` instead. `new Object()` will give developers pause because it's out of the ordinary. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597926/what-is-the-difference-between-new-object-and-object-literal-notation Also, using `{}` syntax, you wouldn't have to type `config.` a boatload of times; it's noise.

Answer (score 0):

I think `window.onbeforeunload = function ()` is operating as soon as the page loads, so what is inside `if(!bool)` is executing on the button press.

Try changing these two lines:

// var bool = false;

```
var bool;
```

// if (!bool) {

```
if (bool == false) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You're testing the flag once, when you assign the `.beforeunload` handler when the page is loaded. Calling `flag()` doesn't re-execute that code. You need to test it when the function is called.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (!bool) {
        return "You haven't clicked the button, do you really want to leave?"
    }
}
```

Comment: You know that the only thing that a `beforeunload` handler is supposed to do is return a message that should be displayed to the user when they try to leave the page, right? So it doesn't seem like your handler is written correctly at all, since it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Then what do you suggest? I want to deliver a popup on exit, but only if the user doesn't click the button.

Comment: Return the message you want to display in the popup.

Comment: The message is supposed to be a form, which is handled by QP_popupMain().