# Javascript multidimensional associated array error

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am to build two dimensional associated array but getting an error

```
while(phpcnt)
{
    pre_id=id
    pre_selected[track]['id']=some id;
    pre_selected[track]['price']=some no;
    console.log(pre_selected[track]['id']);
    console.log(pre_selected[track]['price']);
    phpcnt=phpcnt-1;
    track=track+1;
}
```

this is array declaraion
   `var pre_selected=new Array();`

and the error is `TypeError: pre_selected[track] is undefined`

Comment: Did you try this `pre_selected['track']['id']`

Comment: this error `TypeError: pre_selected[track] is undefined` hints that, surprise!, `pre_selected[track]` is _undefined_, so you can't assign property to it

Comment: @RichS [What is the difference between `new Object()` and object literal notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597926/what-is-the-difference-between-new-object-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: JavaScript doesn't *have* associative arrays. The closest thing to PHP's associative arrays are Objects. Please see the linked duplicate for more details.

Comment: @RichS, in your comment you suggest use new Object, but in most cases enough literal object, as more readable and in post by link from my comment also about this