# for in loop through properties of an object literal VS an object initialized constructed from Object

Tags: javascript

I'm asked by an interviewer, is there a difference between the following code:

```
var o1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
}

for( var p in o1) {
    // ...
}
```

vs

```
var o2 = new Object()
o2.a = 1;
o2.b = 2;
o2.c = 3;

for( var p in o2) {
   // ...
}
```

I can't think of any difference, is there any??

Comment: I would tentatively say no... I could be wrong.

Comment: No difference, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: I would also say no. But it may differ at runtime (thinking about which side of the `=`-sign the different things are).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between \`new Object()\` and object literal notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597926/what-is-the-difference-between-new-object-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the semi-colon missing from the `new Object()` line is unintentional, then there is no difference...

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp

...except that the first one — according to this comment — executes faster.

> The two examples above do exactly the same. There is no need to use new Object().
>   For simplicity, readability and execution speed, use the first one (the object literal method).

Comment: @Rayon ...because... why exactly?

Comment: So no actual reason other than that someone on SE generally don't like them and justifies with using the same kind of vague and unspecified arguments they accuse W3 schools for.

Comment: Then post an answer referencing that instead of wasting our time with these comments. Are you here to help or just go "That's no good"?

Comment: If _"That's no good"_ will improve the quality of the answer and will help the future users then _"YES"_, I am am here for that...

Comment: It does not. It just negs an answer without any kind of guidance to a better alternative, it antagonizes and annoys, it does not help.

Comment: [__MDN__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) is definitely better alternative than _your_ _w3schoold_

Comment: Then post an **answer** with that reference instead and stop using up our time with these non-substantiated "It's worse/better, because I say it is" statements.