# Object.create({}): Is is a good practice?

Tags: javascript

I've been talking to some professionals who work with JavaScript in a company, and I've been told that it isn't a good practice to create an object instance using either `new` or the global object `{}`, even if I want an empty object, like this:

```
var wrong1 = new Object();
var wrong2 = {};
```

The correct way, according to them and the company's standards, is to create it like this:

```
var correct = Object.create({});
```

Passing an empty object as the prototype of an empty object seems rather over-engineered, and maybe even purposeless.

Can someone provide me an answer as to why this is recommended, or if it isn't, why not? (possible pros. and cons.)

Comment: But isn't passing empty object literal `{}` wrong according to those guidelines? Wouldn't  `Object.create(Object.create({}))` be better? ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between \`new Object()\` and object literal notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597926/what-is-the-difference-between-new-object-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: @el.pescado - that's good, but this is bullet proof: `function create(){return Object.create(create())}`

Comment: There's no such thing as "global object {}".

Comment: what is an empty object? one without any prototypes?

Comment: @Oleg don't see how the duplicate link you provided is a duplicate. Doesn't really discuss Object.create. Related yes...duplicate no

Comment: @charlietfl I've seen similar questions a few times already. People are wondering about the best way to create objects. Use `var a = {};`, it has been answered many times already.

Comment: @Oleg but that's not what is being asked here

Comment: @Oleg what is being asked here is *why* would this be a standard practice within a software company, I mean, the real advantages and the disadvantages if any. I believe it is an important concept.

Comment: @Oleg Furthermore, the question you linked barely references `Object.create` while here I am explicitly asking about it.

Comment: There might be some cases when you want your object to have no prototype using `Object.create(null)`. For example if you need some sort of caching and you want to avoid name collisions and don't want to use `hasOwnProperty`. But `Object.create({})` looks like a complete overhead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The object literal will create an object with the following prototype chain.

```
Object.prototype -> {}
```

The literal syntax is heavily optimized by most engines because it's such a common pattern.

To compare, `Object.create({})` creates an object with a longer prototype chain.

```
Object.prototype -> {} -> {}
```

The instance (on the far right) has a prototype of `{}`, which as seen before already has a prototype of `Object.prototype`.

`Object.create` is a very useful function for creating objects with custom prototypes and it doesn't suffer from the same problems as `new`. However, we don't *need* it here because `{}` already creates an object with a shorter prototype chain.

I don't know why anyone would think that adding this extra layer of indirection (and performance loss) was a "best practice".

If anything, I'd say that the literal syntax was safer—as there's no way for `{}` to be accidentally/maliciously redefined, unlike `Object` which can be shadowed.

```
var Object = 3;
// ...
Object.create({}) // TypeError: Object.create is not a function(...)
```

Of course, this doesn't mean you should never use `Object`, but in this case I think that `{}` is the simplest tool for the job and as a result, it has the best performance too.

Comment: You have a really good point. `Object` can be shadowed and so can the `.create` function.

Comment: My guess is someone was being really anal and decided that if `Object.create()` exists...then it simply has to be better

Comment: So by this comment, I can assume that `var a = {}` is even safer than `var b = new Object()`?

Comment: @BrunoFinger Yep. Prefer literal syntax when possible, it's the easiest to read (for other programmers) and optimise (for the compiler).

Comment: Moral of the story: don't let people tell you what a best practise is without a solid justification as to why it is one.