# Choosing between object creation via constructor and object-literal syntax

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript one can make an object by using the incorporated constructor of Object:

```
var person = new Object();
person.firstName = 'John';
person.lastName = 'Doe';
```

Almost all people seem to prefer the way of object-creation as a literal:

```
var person2 = {
  firstName: 'Peter',
  lastName: 'Smith'
}
```

Now I'm wondering:
Why is the constructor-way ignored completely?

But especially: 
Are there cases in which one should prefer one way over the other?

I mean the constructor-way must be in there for some reason ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between \`new Object()\` and object literal notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597926/what-is-the-difference-between-new-object-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: if you don't need inheritance, stick with literals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I mean the constructor-way must be in there for some reason ...

The `Object` constructor was originally the only way to create an object. The object initializer syntax (`{}`) was [added in JavaScript 1.2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.2), the updated JavaScript in Netscape Navigator 4.0 in 1997.

There are several reasons to prefer initializer syntax to the `Object` constructor:

- It's shorter
- It's more expressive, particularly when using property initializers
- It can't be overridden/shadowed (whereas `Object` can be)<sup>1</sup>

In contrast, there is basically no reason to use `Object` to create objects except indirectly, when using a variable that might point to the `Object` function or might point to some other function, e.g.:

```
function constructAndInit(ctor, props) {
    var obj = new ctor();
    if (props) {
        for (var key in props) {
            obj[key] = props[key];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

// Maybe use use Object...
var foo = constructAndInit(Object);

// ...or maybe you use somnething else
var bar = constructAndInit(NiftyThingy);
```

We do, of course, routinely use the `Object` function **without** calling it to create objects:

- Any time we want to get access to the root object prototype, `Object.prototype`
- To use the functions that are properties of `Object`, like `Object.create`, `Object.defineProperty`, and such

---

<sup>1</sup> *"can't be overridden/shadowed (whereas `Object` can be)"* Here's an example of shadowing `Object`:

```js
function foo() {
    var Object = {
        foo: "bar"
    };

    // ...later...
    var o = new Object(); // fails
}
foo();
```

Comment: _"It can't be overridden (whereas Object can be)"_ Can you further describe  this portion of Answer?

Comment: @guest271314: Added above.