# Object Literal Vs Prototypical Inheritance memory/performance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I've been following classical inheritance vs Prototypical inheritance but I've got a doubt.

When we create an object using

```
var a = {};
and 
var a = new Object();
```

I read that new creates a 'copy' of an object (hence it's bad?) but at the same time, I read they both are the same thing here([What is the difference between `new Object()` and object literal notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597926/what-is-the-difference-between-new-object-and-object-literal-notation))

I'm kinda confused if someone can explain what exactly is going on.

Comment: Both are same, there is no difference. new doesn't create copy of object it creates an instance of a class.

Comment: @SanchayKumar Now this is even more confusing,  lets say if it's function instead of an object it will create a new function all together right? For example 

`var Employee = function (name, company, salary) {
    this.name = name || "";
    this.company = company || "";
    this.salary = salary || 5000;
}

var emp1 = new Employee("John","Pluto",3000);
`

In this case new object emp1 is created everytime we call it with new. How come it's not the case with new Object()?

Comment: **Employee** here is a construction function, calling it with new will create a new object. Calling it with new everytime will create a new object.
Same is true for Object, **new Object** will also create a separate plain object everytime.

Comment: @SanchayKumar then it's a bad practise to do 'new' everytime? instead use {}? is my question.. if that's true..then how are they the same?

Comment: Both are same because the output will be same.
But, {} will definitely take less space and performance wise it might be evaluated faster. But, those differences are negligible.