# jslint: How to suppress 'Expected 'Object.create(null)' and instead saw 'new Object'. warning?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jslint

How to avoid jslint to shout at me with the warning

> 'Expected 'Object.create(null)' and instead saw 'new Object'

when using this very simple line of code:

```
var myDummyObject = new Object();
```

?

Comment: Not sure why jslint doesn't like that, but you can do `var myDummyObject = {};`  It may, in general not like the `new Object()` and `new Array()` forms and prefer the static declarations such as `{}` and `[]`;   `Object.create(null)` creates a special object with an empty prototype so it won't have methods such as `.hasOwnProperty()` which is sometimes useful, but usually not required.

Comment: @jfriend00 yup I know jslint is fine with other forms, was just curious about why it complains that one in particular.

Comment: Well, jslint is opinionated and you use it because you want to know its opinion about things.  Apparently, it has an opinion that `new Object()` should not be used.  The issue you see is documented here: http://www.jslint.com/help.html.  It does not say why.  Lots of discussion about it here: [What is the difference between `new Object()` and object literal notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597926/what-is-the-difference-between-new-object-and-object-literal-notation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, jslint is opinionated and you use it because you want to know its opinion about things.  Apparently, it has an opinion that `new Object()` should not be used.  The issue you see is documented here: http://www.jslint.com/help.html.  It does not say why.

Lots of discussion about it here: [What is the difference between `new Object()` and object literal notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597926/what-is-the-difference-between-new-object-and-object-literal-notation).  The `{}` syntax is both faster and shorter than `new Object()` which sounds like enough of a reason to prefer it.

As you apparently know, you can use either of these:

```
var myDummyObject = {};
var myDummyObject = Object.create(null);
```

The latter will create an object with an empty prototype so it won't have methods on it like `.hasOwnProperty()` which is occasionally useful though usually not needed.