# Why do I need 'new' to create an object?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript and I just came up with this thought

Why do I need 'new' to create an object?

```
function a(){};
var b = new a();
var c = {};
c.__proto__ = a.prototype;
```

If I create an object and point it's `__proto__` to the constructor's prototype.
Is it the same way to create an object using `new`?

Comment: Your code is not valid.

Comment: first line should be **function a() {};**

Comment: Sorry about the error, I just edited it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between \`new Object()\` and object literal notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597926/what-is-the-difference-between-new-object-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, they would be equivalent (although `__proto__` has been historically discouraged because it wasn't properly standardized), but only because the definition of `a` is empty.

If `a` would perform some initialization, it would not be done for `c`.

As for why `new` is necessary, the difference between calling `a()` and `new a()` would be the context object (`this` would be the global object or the newly created object).

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you do not *need* anything. Javascript just has slightly different ways of creating objects which (of course) work slightly different. In your examples:

```js
function a() = {}; // syntax error, correct syntax is function a() {}
var b = new a(); // creates a new instance of a - assuming a is a constructor function
var c = {}; // creates a new object literal
c.__proto__ = a.prototype // assings the prototype of function a to __proto__ of c
```

As a basic rule of thumb, if you simply want to create an object use the object literal way. If you want to use the constructor pattern you wanna use the `new` keyword to create instances using the constructor - you can also create instances manually but `new` is syntactic sugar. I would try to avoid directly assigning objects to the `__proto__` since that is usually done internally. Another way to create objects based on other objects is using `Object.create({})`.

The latest ES syntax introduces the `class` keyword to abstract out the constructor pattern. This is a polarizing feature of the language. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3658673/5289923).

Hope it helps, happy learning!

Comment: Sorry again about the syntax error.Thanks for your answer, it helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

firstly,the `__proto__` only support on safari,chrome,firefox,not supported by IE，and which has not yet become a standard.

```
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.run = function() {
    console.log(this.name + 'can run...');
}

var cat = new Animal('cat');
```

to simulation the `new` process  as below：

```
//Simulation process
new Animal('cat')=function(){
    let obj={};  //create an empty object
    obj.__proto__=Animal.prototype; 
    //obj->Animal.prototype->Object.prototype->null
    return Animal.call(obj,'cat');// bind this to the instantiated object
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So the real simulation for `new` is much more complicate because the real constructor is not empty. The keyword `new` helps to simplify the process?