# Setting Function as Object member with "new" notation

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

everybody, I'm new in **Javascript**... I know how to incorporate a function into an Object using this format...

```
var xyz = {
    yearOfBirth: 1963,
    calculateAge: function() {
        this.age = (new Date().getFullYear()) - this.yearOfBirth;
    }
};
```

***But I need your guidance on this other format...

```
var abc = new Object();
```

Thanks!

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597926/what-is-the-difference-between-new-object-and-object-literal-notation

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, don't use `new Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your question. When a object is defined using a constructor, properties can be defined like so:

```
var abc = new Object()
abc["yearOfBirth"]=1963

abc["calculateAge"]=function(){
    this.age=(new Date().getFullYear())-this.yearOfBirth;
}
```

you can also do this:

```
var abc = new Object()
abc.yearOfBirth=1963

abc.calculateAge=function(){
    this.age=(new Date().getFullYear())-this.yearOfBirth;
}
```

Comment: also without quotes, like `abc.yearOfBirth = 1963`

Comment: Thank you for your input @BalázsÉdes I will ad that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you both for your help and quick response.

Comment: I was once one like you @CarlosMalovini, I understand.