# Is there a difference between {} and new Object()

Tags: javascript, object

I was asked this in an interview. I couldn't answer. Not sure if it was a trick question.

`let a = {}`

and

`let a = new Object`

Comment: Possible duplicate -- [What is the difference between \`new Object()\` and object literal notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597926/what-is-the-difference-between-new-object-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5513376/2617344

Answer (score 0):

```
new Object()
```

has a default argument value of {}

You can also initialize an Array with new Object

```
const a = new Object([]);
```

See [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597926/what-is-the-difference-between-new-object-and-object-literal-notation)