# Is there a difference between get() {} and get: function() {}?

Tags: javascript

So yeah, is there a difference between `get() {}` and `get: function() {}` declaration in objects or this is completely two different things?

Actually I can't get `get: function() {}` to work even like a simple method, but as a getter too.

So maybe the question must sounds like: What the `get: function() {}` is?

Thanks.

UPD: http://take.ms/h6xII - here is of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Do you mean `get() {}` or `get property() {}`, since you're talking about getters?

Comment: I suggest you read about scopes, functions and objects in JavaScript, you'll get your answer there. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: When you say... "get: function()" are you making the declaration inside of a class? I'd recommend showing the two declaration styles in a complete example.

Comment: @P.Lalonde that has nothing todo with scope, and i think the op is already aware of functions + objects in a neccessary way... ( and please dont recommend w3schools, they just give snippets while MDN includes explanation + advanced stuff)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does this object method definition work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32404617/1048572)?

Comment: No, its not a duplicate. ES5 have that notation for object methods too.
And what is the difference between `get() {}` and `get property() {}`?

Comment: So as I understood `get: function named() {}` is completely different from getter and named function just able to call itself in recursion? Right?

Comment: @almazmusic You still didn't post any code. Even that screenshot you shared doesn't show how `p` and `s` are defined.

Comment: @almazmusic And no, `get() {}` is an ES6 shorthand (roughly for `get: function() {}`). If that is not what are talking about, please remove it from your question. `get property() {}` is the ES5 getter syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually no, the one version is the new [shorthand in es6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

```
var someObject = {
    get() {
    }
};
```

which is actually pretty much the same as

```
var someObject = {
    get: function() {
    }
};
```

they are both method definitions, it's just part of the new shorthand notation

**Update**

I updated the answer a bit after seeing your screenshot. The difference between the getter/setters for `p` & `s` are because in `p` they are added through the [`object initializer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), and in `s` they are added through the [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) method.

I added a small example which should give you a similar output inside the console as the screenshot you were showing (provided you run it on chrome, on firefox it looks slightly different ;) )

```js
// property getter/setter through object initializer
var p = { 
  _x: 5, 
  get x() { 
    return this._x; 
  }, 
  set x(v) { 
    this._x = v; 
  } 
};

// get/set function through defineProperty
var s = { _y: 10 };
Object.defineProperty( s, 'y', {
  get() {
    return this._y;
  },
  set(v) {
    this._y = v;
  }
});

p.x = 10;
s.y = 20;

console.log(p);
console.log(s);
```

Comment: Actually neither are *declarations*.

Comment: These are both function expressions neither of these will get hoisted.

Comment: @TimeDead The first one isn't even that. It's just a *method definition*.

Comment: I'm not talking about es5 vs es6+. I'm talking about es5 only and should mention that.

Comment: Concerning to shorthand from ES6 - getter and setter have that shorthand notation in ES5 too.

Comment: @almazmusic I updated the answer a bit, I hope this suits your question better

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the first example as function `get() {}` and the 2nd example as an object like

```
var obj = {
   get: function() {}
};
```

The only main difference between the above and

```
var obj = {
  get() {}
};
```

Is that the 2nd is a shorthand in es6 both are function expressions.

Comment: OP didn't use `function get` anywhere?

Comment: You are correct, I don't know why I thought OP did. I shall fix my answer, thank you.