# async function example() or async example()?

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

Why writing this is wrong:

```
'use strict'

async example1 () {
  return 'example 1'
}

async example2 () {
  return 'example 2'
}

export { example1, example2 }
```

But it is fine like this:

```
export default {
  async example1 () {
    return 'example 1'
  },
  async example2 () {
    return 'example 2'
  }
}
```

It is quite confusing. I assume the latter is wrong too.

Any explanations for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour has nothing to do with `async` or `export`. It is part of ES6 enhanced object properties:

- http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand
- http://es6-features.org/#MethodProperties

These are equivalent:

```
const foo = 123;
const a = {
  foo: foo,
  bar: function bar() { return 'bar'; },
  baz: async function baz() { return await something(); },
};
```

and

```
const foo = 123;
const a = {
  foo,
  bar() { return 'bar'; },
  async baz() { return await something(); },
};
```

Comment: thanks for this. can I do `baz: async baz() { return await something(); },`?

Comment: @teelou: No. You need the `function` keyword to define functions (object method syntax and arrow functions are the exceptions). So you could do `baz: async function() {...}` or `baz: async () => {...}` or `baz: async function baz() {...}`.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks. `object method syntax and arrow functions are the exceptions` - fair enough...

Answer (score 4):

The first tries (but fails) to declare multiple individual functions, while the second creates an object literal with several [method definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32404617/1048572) that is then default exported. Btw, it's the same without the `async` keyword. You'll want to use

```
export async function example1() {
  return 'example 1'
}

export async function example2() {
  return 'example 2'
}
```