# Vuex: Difference between Function Declarations and Function name as Key in Mutation

Tags: javascript, vuex

I have the following Vuex structure.

(store/actions.js store/mutations.js, ...)

And I have seen two cases when writing a function in a mutation

**case 1**

```
import {
  MUTATION_ONE
  MUTATION_TWO
  ...
} from './mutation_group';

export default {
  [SOME_MUTATION](parameter) { .. }
};
```

**case 2**

```
import {
  MUTATION_ONE
  MUTATION_TWO
  ...
} from './mutation_group';

export default {
  SOME_MUTATION: function (parameter) { .. }
};
```

What is the difference between simply using function declarations and using variables as key values ​​via computed property name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [How does this object method definition work without the “function” keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404617/how-does-this-object-method-definition-work-without-the-function-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 and 2 are interchangeable only if `MUTATION_ONE === 'MUTATION_ONE'`, while computed properties in case 1 guarantee that correct mutation name will be specified regardless of `SOME_MUTATION` value.

It's common for action types to be uppercased constants in Redux naming convention but they don't necessary have to be of the same value, action type could be namespaced:

```
export const MUTATION_ONE = 'FOO/MUTATION_ONE';
```

This Redux structure and underlying issues don't have to be applicable to Vuex. Vuex addresses this case with [modules and namespaces](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing).