# Referencing an object property inside itself

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a javascript class like this:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor (a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  foo() {
    // do something
  }

  bar() {
    const baz = this.foo();
    // do something with baz
  }
}
```

In the `bar()` function I can call the `foo()` function using `this`.

Is it possible to do this using an object instead of a class? For example:

```
const myObj = (a) => {
  return {
    foo: () => {
      // do something
    },
    bar: () => {
      const baz = foo(); // this doesn't work
      const baz = myObj.foo() // this doesn't work either
      // do something with baz
    }
  }
}
```

A solution I found is to define `foo` and `bar` outside of the object and then assign them to the object afterwards, but it doesn't feel right:

```
const myObj = (a) => {
  const foo = () => {
    // do something
  };
  const bar = () => {
    const baz = foo();
    // do something with baz
  };

  return { foo, bar };
}
```

Is there a way to reference an object's own property from inside of the object?

Edit: Thanks to the responders, an easy solution is to not use arrow functions, and then you can use `this`:

```
const myObj = (a) => {
  return {
    foo: function () {
      // do something
    },
    bar: function () {
      const baz = this.foo() // this works!
      // do something with baz
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, in very much the same way as in an object created from a class. Why did you change the methods to arrow functions, and why did you remove `this`?

Comment: This has been asked here countless times for over a decade :)

Comment: @vsync I can't find a decent duplicate

Comment: @evolutionxbox - I've seen a dup many many years ago.. need to remember...

Comment: Sorry I edited the question, I forgot the class had a constructor and so I changed the non-class version to a function taking in the same values as the constructor.

Comment: @Bergi I just wanted to convert it into a regular old object instead of using classes. I don't have any specific reason why, I just prefer using regular objects instead of classes if possible.

Comment: @bradlet - `Class` is used to create instances with shared properties or inherit from other classes and expand upon them. `Object` is used for a single-purpose use case, without any shared-properties capabilities. You don't go around changing Classes to Object just because you can.. each situation has a use-case for one or the other.

Comment: @bradlet I was not talking about the conversion of `class` to an object literal. I was talking about the conversion of [`foo() { … }` method syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32404617/1048572) to `foo: () => {…}` arrow functions, and the removal of `this.` before the method call.

Comment: Not sure how to mark this question as solved, but thank you to whoever linked me to the related question. This is solved easily enough by not using arrow functions, which allows you to use `this` to reference the object itself.