# Is it possible to call methods created by factory function?

Tags: javascript, composition

If I compose some methods with factory function below.

```
function createCrudMethods() {
  return {
    findMany: async () => {
    },
    findOne: async () => {
    },
    createOne: async () => {
    },
    deleteOne: async () => {
    },
    updateOne: async () => {
    },
  };
}
```

Can I do something like this?

```
const object = {
  ...createCrudMethods();
  createOneWithNumber() {
    // do some cool stuff
    createOne() // error undefined
  }
}
```

or maybe there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of `function` scope to refer to yourself using `this`:

```js
function createCrudMethods() {
  return {
    findMany: () => console.log('findMany'),
    findOne: () => console.log('findOne'),
    createOne: () => console.log('createOne'),
    deleteOne: () => console.log('deleteOne'),
    updateOne: () => console.log('updateOne')
  };
}

const object = {
  ...createCrudMethods(),
  createOneWithNumber() {
    // do some cool stuff
    console.log('createOneWithNumber');
    this.createOne();
  }
};

// Console should show:
// - createOneWithNumber
// - createOne
object.createOneWithNumber();
```

Comment: This wasn't an anonymous function. It will work fine with the previous syntax

Comment: `{ createOneWithNumber() {  } }` is basically the shorthand of `{ createOneWithNumber: function() {  } }` [How does this object method definition work without the "function" keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32404617)

Comment: My apologies, yup @Konrad and @VLAZ is right, the only change needed is the `this.` keyword, thanks for correction!