# Question about Javascript / TypeScript modules, exporting, importing and function / object declarations

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise

I'm new to TypeScript and also modules in general. Here's a file/module and I need some guidance on what exactly is happening:

```
export default function MyAdapter (client: Pool): AdapterType {
  return {
    async foo (
      bar: barType
    ): Promise<returnType> {
      ...
      return Promise<returnType>;
    },
    async myFunc ({
      param1,
      param2
    }: {
      param3: string
      param4: string
    }): Promise<returnType2> {
      ...
      return Promise<returnType2>;
    },
  }
}
```

I'm importing and trying to do something like this:

```
import MyAdapter from "./adapter";

const pool = new Pool(...);

export default async function handler() {
  const val = await MyAdapter(pool).foo(bar);
  ....
}
```

But I get the following TypeScript errors when doing a tsc transpile:

```
src/app/api/path/route.ts:14:12 - error TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

14      await MyAdapter(pool).foo(bar);
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing this wrong because I'm ignorant of something basic and foundational to TypeScript or the way the modules work.

Also, what is the notation called on how the Adapter function is declared with nested functions within the top return block?

Comment: Where exactly is TypeScript complaining?

Comment: "*what is the notation called on how the Adapter function is declared with nested functions within the top return block?*" - [method definition syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32404617/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi It's complaining when doing a tsc transpile

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the links. I realized that the adapter module is returning an object with async functions as properties. Is the way I'm invoking them correct e.g. `await MyAdapter(pool).foo(bar);`

Comment: I cannot reproduce. What exactly is `AdapterType`? Are the methods declared as optional in there?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your response. The type is actually `Adapter` from NextAuth's `@auth/core/adapters`. I just changed it to `AdapterType` in my question. I checked the declaration file and indeed it seems that those methods are declared as optional. What can be done to work around this?

Comment: Either don't use that type if it doesn't represent your object faithfully, or use a non-null assertion

Answer (score -1):

Exporting and importing modules in Typescript is same as that of JavaScript. But you need to specify that the module you are trying to import in another file must not be the type of `undefined`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).