# JAvascript "has no method"

Tags: javascript

when it goes to line 21 it thinks there is no function deposit
I am confuced as it should have that function. Please explain why.

```
1   function makeBankAccount(){
2     var bala = 0
3     function balance(b)
4     {
5       return bala;
6     }
7     function withdraw(b)
8     {
9       bala = bala - b;
10    }
11    function deposit(b)
12    {
13      bala = bala + b;
14    }
15    return makeBankAccount;
16  }
17  
18  var account1 = makeBankAccount();
19  var account2 = makeBankAccount();
20  
21  account1.deposit(5); 
22  console.log(account1.balance()); // -> 5
23  account1.withdraw(5);
24  console.log(account1.balance()); // -> 0
25  
26  account2.withdraw(5);
27  account2.withdraw(5);
28  account2.deposit(5); 
29  account2.deposit(5); 
30  account2.deposit(5);
31  account2.deposit(5);
32  console.log(account2.balance()); // -> 10
```

Comment: If you're trying to create an object that has methods with `makeBankAccount()`, you're doing it wrong.  Please go find a very basic tutorial on creating an object with methods in Javascript.  This isn't something we should be answering here.  Here's a good place to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a method for a custom object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504803/how-do-you-create-a-method-for-a-custom-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your function `deposit(b)` is not global.

`deposit(b)` is only accessible inside make `makeBankAccount()` and your objects are present outside. So `deposit(b)` is out of scope.

Also `new` keyword is missing in object creation. 
Change it to:

Object 1:

```
var account1 = new makeBankAccount();
```

Object 2:

```
var account2 = new makeBankAccount();
```

Comment: But isnt the account2 an instance of  makebankaccount?

Comment: no it is not ... no new keyword, and makebankaccount has no (new) methods on it's prototype

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can do this:

```
function makeBankAccount(){
    var bala = 0

    function balance(b) {
        return bala;
    }

    function withdraw(b) {
        bala = bala - b;
    }

    function deposit(b) {
        bala = bala + b;
    }
    return {
        balance: balance,
        withdraw: withdraw,
        deposit: deposit
    };
}
```

Then your usage code will be unchanged

or

```
function makeBankAccount(){
    this.bala = 0
}

makeBankAccount.prototype.balance = function(b) {
    return this.bala;
};

makeBankAccount.prototype.withdraw = function(b) {
    this.bala -= b;
};

makeBankAccount.prototype.deposit = function (b) {
    this.bala += b;
};
```

then your instantiate account1/account2 like

```
var account1 = new makeBankAccount();
var account2 = new makeBankAccount();
```

The rest of the code rmains unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
var balance = 10; //You may have the balance saved anywhere else. Get it here.
var makeBankAccount = {
    amount: 0,
    balance: function () {
        return balance;
    },
    withdraw: function () {
        return balance - this.amount;
    },
    deposit: function () {
        return balance + this.amount;
    }
}
function Balance() {
  document.getElementById("Balance").innerHTML = makeBankAccount.balance();
}
function Withdraw(x) {
  makeBankAccount.amount = x;
  document.getElementById("Withdraw").innerHTML = makeBankAccount.withdraw();
}
function Deposit(x) {
  makeBankAccount.amount = x;
  document.getElementById("Deposit").innerHTML = makeBankAccount.deposit();
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <button onclick="Balance()">Balance</button>
  <button onclick="Withdraw(6)">Withdraw</button>
  <button onclick="Deposit(7)">Deposit</button>
  <p id="Balance"></p>
  <p id="Withdraw"></p>
  <p id="Deposit"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Remaining is upto you to get the `balance` and pass the `amount` to the functions.