# Member Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we use a variable as a function.
Following is my code

```
$(document).mouseup(function (evt) {
            balls.push(new ball(mousePos["downX"],
                mousePos["downY"],
                5 + (Math.random() * 10), 0.9, randomColor()));
        });

function ball(positionX, positionY, radius, color) {
            this.px = positionX;
            this.py = positionY;
            this.rad = radius;
            this.clr = color;
            this.draw = drawFun(this.px, this.py, this.rad, this.clr);
        }
function drawFun(x, y, r, c) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle = c;
            ctx.fill();
            //stroke
            ctx.lineWidth = r * 0.1;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
            ctx.stroke();
        }

for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
                //TODO: DRAW ALL BALLS
                balls[i].draw;

            }
```

Now i want to use `ball[i].draw;`  but in console it tells that draw is undefined. How can i access drawFun from `ball[i]`

Comment: Before mouseup happen, how will you access that balls array?

Comment: Yes am talking about after the mouseUp. Balls array is getting balls in it on mouseUp  and drawFun is executing once but i want it to be executed in for loop as well

Comment: `this.draw = drawFun(this.px, this.py, this.rad, this.clr);` is not creating a function. You need something like `this.draw = function() { ....}`  or have drawFun return a function or be the function: this.draw = drawFun;

Comment: You can try `this.draw = drawFun`. An alternative would be to add the draw (or drawFun) function to the prototype of ball.

Comment: Likely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504803/how-do-you-create-a-method-for-a-custom-object-in-javascript but I will not use my hammer here

Answer (score 1):

Use `ball[i].draw(); // notice the parenthesis, to execute function.` And use this:

`this.draw = function() { drawFun(this.px, this.py, this.rad, this.clr); }`

Without `function() { .. }` you are simply storing what is returned by drawFun, which is this case is undefined.

Comment: by using ball[i].draw(); it simply tells draw is not a function

Comment: Use the `this.draw = function() { ... }` as well @AnilKumar

Comment: You need to move the for loop inside the ready function as well