# Call JavaScript function in another file using JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call one JavaScript function from another JavaScript file

below is my code:

```
 var exJS = function () {
     function coolMethod() {
       alert("hello suraj");
     }
  }
```

when I call the function

```
var myClass = new exJS();
myClass.coolMethod();
```

Why do I get the error that `coolmethod` is not defined?

Comment: Take a look at the javascript Module pattern!

Comment: Google: "define class javascript". First result: https://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a method for a custom object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504803/how-do-you-create-a-method-for-a-custom-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

For it to be accessible externally, you need to define the child function using the `this` reference of the parent function, like this:

```js
var exJS = function() {
  this.coolMethod = function() {
    alert("hello suraj");
  }
}

var myClass = new exJS();
myClass.coolMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var exJS = function (){
  function coolMethod() {
    alert("hello suraj");
   }
}
```

this essentially translates to :

```
 var exJS = function (){
  var coolMethod = function () {
    alert("hello suraj");
   };
}
```

as you can see `coolMethod` is just a local variable pointing to a function.

use :

```
this.coolMethod = function () {
        alert("hello suraj");
       };
```

so `coolMethod` becomes a member of `exJS`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using the Class declaration:

```
class exJS {
    coolMethod () {
    alert("hello suraj");
  }
}


var myClass = new exJS();
myClass.coolMethod();
```